# MVC controller not returning JSON data?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

I was returning JSON data of a Product from a controller `JsonDetailsProduct`. This is in turn called using the Jquery.

However, the success function of the Jquery call doesn't seems to be receiving any data. I guess Something is wrong within my controller.

MVC Controller:

```
    public ActionResult JsonDetailsProduct(int id)
{ 
    Product pdt = NWDC.GetProduct(id); 
    if (pdt == null)
 { 
    // i'm throwing a custom exception here
    throw new RecordNotFoundException(); 
 } 
else
 { 
    return Json(new { 
    ProductId = prod.ProductID, 
    ProductName = prod.ProductName, 
    UnitPrice = prod.UnitPrice, 
    UnitsInStock = prod.UnitsInStock, 
    Discontinued = prod.Discontinued 
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
  } 
}
```

the JQuery call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
  function(){   
    alert("About to make the call"); // just added it for my debugging purpose
   $.getJSON( "/SlimProductServices/JsonDetailsProduct",  
               data:{id:$('#txtProductID').val()},
    function(productData)
    {
      alert(productData);
    }
    );
 }
);
```

Any thoughts where things are setup wrongly and whether any issue in Jquery Call also present ??

**EDIT**
Also, I corrected the  `data` parameter of my Jquery call, but the first Alert box shows up after that blank pop ups.

Comment: where is the id parameter in your ajax call ? what do you get when browsing /SlimProductServices/JsonDetailsProduct ?

Comment: I'm still not adding the data anywhere . I was firstly checking whether i'm really receiving any data.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't seem to be receiving data"? Is the success function getting called at all? (Do you see the alert? If it works you'd probably see something like `[object Object]`.)

Comment: Are you sure your route definitions are ok for this missing id ?  What do you get when browsing /SlimProductServices/JsonDetailsProduct ?

Comment: Your edited version has a syntax error: `data:id:$(...` is invalid, you can't have two colons like that without curly brackets. Perhaps it should be `{data : { id : $(...) } }` or just `{ id : $(...) }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `id`?

```
$.getJSON( "/SlimProductServices/JsonDetailsProduct", { 'id': 1 },...

public ActionResult JsonDetailsProduct(int id)
```

Take a look at [getJson](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) in the jquery docs.

Where are you getting the ID from? If you just want to test the call without changing your jquery call, you could add a second Action method...

```
public ActionResult JsonDetailsProduct()
{ 
    Product pdt = NWDC.GetProduct(1); //hard code product Id that exists for testing.
```

Comment: Do you have a product of ID 1? put a breakpoint on the method to make sure it's being called, and use a tool like Firebug or chrome dev tools to test the javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this solves your issue, I just gave a simple run with your code.

Here is what I have tried:-

```
public ActionResult JsonDetailsProduct(int id)
{
    Product pdt = GetProduct(id);
    if (pdt == null)
    {
        // i'm throwing a custom exception here
        throw new RecordNotFoundException();
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(new Product //Comment:-Added the Object Type
        {
            ProductId = pdt.ProductId,//Comment:-Sure if its 'prod' and not pdt ?
            ProductName = pdt.ProductName,
            UnitPrice = pdt.UnitPrice,
            UnitsInStock = pdt.UnitsInStock,
            Discontinued = pdt.Discontinued
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Two changes which I have made mentioned it as `Comment:-`, please have a look.

Secondly, I have tried with `$.ajax` , for which the code is as follows:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/SlimProductServices/JsonDetailsProduct/'+$('#txtProductID').val(),
        type: 'GET',
        //data: $('#txtProductID').val(), //You can un-comment it later
        success: function (datos) {
            console.log(datos);
        },
    });
});
</script>
```

I am getting proper values returned from my `Action Method`. Just try it out.